# How to stop the custom click event running

Tags: javascript, jquery-click-event

I have javascript custom click event which I want to return false the click event running. The following is my code but seems not success. It will check if the comment is empty, then not jumping back to previous windows. If the comment is not empty, then the FeedbackModal will be shown.

```
$(document).on('click.feed', '#back',  function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#FeedbackModal').toggle();

    str = $('input[name="comment"]').val();
    str = str.trim();
    if (str == "") {
        alert("comment cannot be empty");
    return false;

});
```

This is the html of the button.

```
<button type="button" id="backtopreviouswindows" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
```

Comment: For your first problem you need to pass `event` parameter to your function.

Comment: `event` should be included as a parameter for the handler function - it has no meaning unless you include it.

Comment: Ohh okay @Archer Thanks. We learn something new everyday. :)

Comment: I add event in as parameter in function(event), when I found the return false  is run, however, the click event is still being run

Comment: Can you show us the markup for the back button or link?  Also, what else is running when you click it?  The function above should stop anything else happening unless it's event propagation (bubbling up through the DOM)

Comment: <button type="button" id="backToFirstPage" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>

Comment: Ah okay - do you want it to not close the modal when you click it?

Comment: 'not close modal' means?  what is the way to implement it?

Comment: What happens when you click the button?  You want to stop it doing something, but what is that?

Comment: When I click the button, it will go back to another form. I have some text field in this form, if I check the text is empty I will stop jump back to another form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161004/discussion-between-want-to-be-calm-and-archer).

Comment: var star_value = $('select[name="star_7"]').val();  
  if (star_value != 0 ) {
   str = $('input[name="comment_7"]').val();
   str = str.trim();
   if (str == "") {
    alert("comment cannot be empty");
    return false;
  }
 }

Comment: This question is very unclear and gets less clear when you answer questions.  You need to create a [MCVE] to help us understand your problem and help you fix it.